# How to COLOR print word document in C#?

Tags: c#, printing, ms-word, office-interop

I want to open an existing Word document from a specific file path and **print** it **automatically** in **color**. The document can then be closed again. The user should notice as little as possible or have to do it himself.

---

With the following code I can print a Word document, but only in black and white. There is apparently no "color" parameter in the printOut() method.

```
Word.Application myWordApp = new Word.Application() { Visible = true };
Word.Document testDoc = myWordApp.Documents.Open(FileName: filePath, ReadOnly: true, Visible: true);
testDoc.Activate();
object range = Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument;
testDoc.PrintOut(Background: true, Range: range, Copies: "1", Collate: true);
```

**Is there any way to print a Word document directly in color?**

---

First ideas, which were dropped again:

- Open the Print Preview using the program and print it out by hand => unnecessary work for users
- Cast in PrintDocument (System.Drawing.Printing) => only for plain text files (.txt), does not work with COM objects

Comment: I believe that it belongs to printer settings - to print in b/w or color - not to word app or word document. So, check the printer settings.

Comment: @VDN: Right, printersettings contain a color attribute.
I could create a PrinterSettings object, but the problem is that I do not have a PrintDocument to which I could assign these printer settings.

Comment: Word uses the default printer. The settings for the default printer (b/w vs. color) are what Word will use. If it's a color printer that prints color by default, Word will print color.